# How do I find elements dropdown menu from Google forms? (elements by NAME, ID, XPATH etc.)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScy-uVa2G2tcDNaoQQFEbHCfWu06QmQeNnIPlI_BQ4Nxr4i-A/viewform')
sleep(2)
#option1
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@role="option" and @data-value]/span'))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//div[@role="option" and @data-value]/span)[3]'))).click()
sleep(2)
#option2
wait2 = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait2.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//div[@role="option" and @data-value]/span)[1]'))).click()
wait2.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//div[@role="option" and @data-value]/span)[2]'))).click()
```

I need to automate google forms using Selenium, and I am stuck here.
In my form there are two dropdowns (option1 and option2) but I can only click the first dropdown.
I want to click on Vietnam in dropdown (option2), but I don't know which one is it. I have tried replacing several elements and none of them working.

Here is the link for the mock forms,
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScy-uVa2G2tcDNaoQQFEbHCfWu06QmQeNnIPlI_BQ4Nxr4i-A/viewform